# How to simulate riscv32 on gem5?

Tags: riscv, gem5

When you look at https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/master/src/arch/riscv/types.hh,you can find out some riscv32 definitions. However, I use the gem5 default RISCV configuration and build a basic simulation with config/example/se.py. It only supports those binaries which build by riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc. Is gem5 support riscv32 (gem5 architecture support page is outdated [link](https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/architecture_support/https://))? How to simulate riscv32 on gem5?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Gem5 has been updated to version 23 and can support RV32. Please specify system. cpu. isa=RiscvISA (riscv_type="RV32") in the Python configuration script